# Analytic line integral causing major confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate

$$
\int_{i\pi}^{\infty+i\pi} e^{-z} dz
$$

I feel I need to parametrize this somehow to integrate between $0$ and $\infty$ maybe.

Bit stuck

Comment: Have you tried $z=x+i\pi$?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how that parametrizes this

Comment: @J.G. Sorry, are you able to elaborate a little more please?

Comment: @J.G.: is saying that if you use the change of variable $z=w+i\pi$ then you get $$\int_{i\pi}^{\infty +i\pi}e^{-z}\,d z=\int_{0}^{\infty }e^{-w-i\pi}\,d w=-1$$ as $e^{-z}$ is analytic (as far as you make sense to the integral in $[0,\infty )$, by example assuming it is an improper integral of Riemann)

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks. I realised where I was confusing myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the expression $\int_{z_1}^{\infty +z_1}f(z)\,d z$ denotes an improper integration in the straight line defined by the map $r\mapsto r+z_1$ for $r\in[0,\infty )$ then
$$
\int_{i\pi}^{\infty +i\pi}e^{-z}\,d z=\lim_{r\to \infty }\int_{i\pi}^{r+i\pi}e^{-z}\,d z=\lim_{r\to \infty }e^{-z}\Big|_{r+i\pi}^{i\pi}=e^{-i\pi}-\lim_{r\to \infty }e^{-r-i\pi}=-1
$$